# Pandas Identify duplicate records, create a new column and add the ID of first occurrence

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I am a newbie in python, so please be mercy with me :)

Let's say, that there is a dataframe like this

```
ID       B        C       D        E        isDuplicated
1       Blue     Green   Blue     Pink           false
2       Red      Green   Red      Green          false
3       Red      Orange  Yellow   Green          false
4       Blue     Pink    Blue     Pink           false
5       Blue     Orange  Pink     Green          false
6       Blue     Orange  Pink     Green          true
7       Red      Orange  Yellow   Green          true
8       Red      Orange  Yellow   Green          true
```

If I have duplicates in the rows with the subset= B,C,D,E.
Then I would like to add an other column 'firstOccurred', which should have the ID of the first occurrence.
My desired dataframe should look like this:

```
ID       B        C       D        E        isDuplicated        firstOccurred
1       Blue     Green   Blue     Pink           false                         
2       Red      Green   Red      Green          false
3       Red      Orange  Yellow   Green          false
4       Blue     Pink    Blue     Pink           false
5       Blue     Orange  Pink     Green          false
6       Blue     Orange  Pink     Green          true               5
7       Red      Orange  Yellow   Green          true               3
8       Red      Orange  Yellow   Green          true               3
```

I would be grateful for any help!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `first` only for roww with `True` passed in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['firstOccurred'] = np.where(df['isDuplicated'], 
                               df.groupby(['B','C','D','E'])['ID'].transform('first'), 
                               np.nan)
print (df)
   ID     B       C       D      E  isDuplicated  firstOccurred
0   1  Blue   Green    Blue   Pink         False            NaN
1   2   Red   Green     Red  Green         False            NaN
2   3   Red  Orange  Yellow  Green         False            NaN
3   4  Blue    Pink    Blue   Pink         False            NaN
4   5  Blue  Orange    Pink  Green         False            NaN
5   6  Blue  Orange    Pink  Green          True            5.0
6   7   Red  Orange  Yellow  Green          True            3.0
7   8   Red  Orange  Yellow  Green          True            3.0
```